# How do I reference a list from a past console app item to another windows form item?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, list

How do I reference a list from a past console app item to another windows form item?
Basically, I am getting a list of email addresses from a past console app and trying to use them from that list, in a windows form for emailing people.

Here is my list code:

```
class MyData
{
    public string ColumnOne { get; set; }
    public string ColumnTwo { get; set; }
    public string ColumnThree { get; set; }
    public string ColumnFour { get; set; }
    public string ColumnFive { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<MyData>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    var data = new MyData
    {
        ColumnOne = reader.GetString(0),
        ColumnTwo = reader.GetString(1),
        ColumnThree = reader.GetString(2),
        ColumnFour = reader.GetString(3),
        ColumnFive = reader.GetString(4),
    };
    list.Add(data);
}

Console.WriteLine("");
foreach (var row in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start Here");
    Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnOne); 
    Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnTwo); 
    Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnThree); 
    Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnFour); // Name
    Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnFive); // Email
    Console.WriteLine(""); 
}

MassMail objForm = new MassMail(); // thats my link to my next window.
```

Comment: what's a "past console app item"? I'm sorry, could u clarify the question.

Comment: starting window is a console app next window when finished with the first window is a windows form. hence, my past or previous "console app."

Comment: Have the form take a List<MyData> parameter.  Having a class called MyData is sort of silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have two applications, one is a console app, and the other is a windows form app that relies on the output of the console app.

Simplest solution:

- You can have your console app write to a file or redirect the output to a file and then make the windows form application read the contents of the file.

More complicated:

- You can redirect the output of your console application directly into the windows form application.

Comment: Yea no its not a different app its all one but different .cs's within one project. I don't know if that means anything. So the second option is all I have really. I really wouldn't want to you another config file. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Sean, If it's the same app, why don't you just pass it as a parameter then? When you said "past console app" I assumed it was a different application

Comment: How would I go about that? like this: x*=x and Console.WriteLine("The value inside the method: {0}", x);  but doesnt this not work if its in a different .cs within the project ? Also, this list may be 3 emails or 1000 emails so a pointer might be a little crazy right?

Comment: @Sean, there aren't any explict pointers in C#. You can put the list of MyData values into a List<MyData> class and then pass that as a parameter to your mailer class.

Comment: Awesome Ill try that! thanks! Sorry I am very used to c and java.

Comment: So would it look this way?:  `class mailList(List<MyData> list){` then inside `return row.ColumnFive;` ?? Thanks.

Comment: @Sean, not sure I understand what you mean.. you can pass it in the constructor and iterate though the list with a foreach loop.

Comment: Ok what im asking for is just the row with the corresponding emails as shown in the code above as `Console.WriteLine(row.ColumnFive); // Email`  
for better understanding my algorithm goes as follows: in console app user input for what people they would like to email, email list along with company name and user is shown corresponding to the user input and put within the columns of List<MyData>. user wants to mail the list. a windows form window opens. Now here in the windows form is where i need this list. Can I call this parameter from the console app? Thanks and sorry for misunderstandings.

Comment: @Sean, I would suggest you reask the question giving more details. I find it hard to help you here with the comments. As I said, you should store the list of people in a list, store it somewhere and pass it as a parameter to a method on the windows form.

Comment: Thanks Can Gencer I have figured it out I appreciate all you have done for me. Sorry if I was unclear. Regards, Sean.